# Change variable (and dependent variables) in imported module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

python_import_test2.py file:

```
AAA = 'test2'
BBB = AAA + '_BBB'
def showBBB():
    print AAA
    print BBB
```

python_import_test1.py file:

```
import python_import_test2 as testimport
testimport.AAA = 'test1'
testimport.showBBB()`
```

As an out I get:

```
test1
test2_BBB
```

How to get:

```
test1
test1_BBB
```

?

Comment: You could assign `BBB` inside the function instead of before it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, the value is not assigned to BBB after you reinitialize AAA. When you import with the statement:

```
    import python_import_test2 as testimport
```

The value of AAA = 'test2'

The value of BBB = 'test2_BBB'

Then you reinitialize AAA

Now, The value of AAA = 'test1'

The value of BBB = 'test2_BBB'

This is what you are getting.

You can initialize BBB inside the function defination to get the desired result.

python_import_test2.py file:

```
AAA = 'test2'

def showBBB():
    print AAA
    BBB = AAA + '_BBB'
    print BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `BBB` is a global variable in `python_import_test2.py` when you import that module python calculate the global variables so it would be `test2_BBB` and then you didn't change it, and just changed `AAA`.

If you want to change that variable you can change it in your function scope.

```
def showBBB():
    print AAA
    BBB = AAA + '_BBB'
    print BBB
```

Note that all we have in python is about run time, so till you don't run the function python doesn't execute it,and when you invoke that function after reassigning the `AAA` python will run it using new variable.